# Getting the IP addresses of a remote machine using the remote machine IP address

Tags: networking, ip, remote-access

Is it possible to get a list of the IP addresses a remote machine is connected to if you only have the IP address of the remote machine. You don't have any other details, no username or password.

(I'm 99% sure this isn't possible but I want confirmation.)

Comment: Just think of it the other way round: If it existed, what could you do with it? Or what could Average Joe Hacker Jr. do with it? This would mean a security issue, I'm afraid...

Comment: I thought the same thing at first. But in practice having a list of connections isn't all that useful for a hacker. It's not as though they can get any of the information sent between connected computers just by knowing they are connected. The only real loss of privacy is being able to turn the IP address into a location, which really doesn't change a lot either unless the person doesn't want people knowing that they have the internet :)

Comment: Is it the same picture, if you view this from an enterprise infrastructure aspect, with having an extended structure, with some web-facing frontend servers too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, however you can do this if you can implement RMI on the remote machine. Anyways it is out of context.

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to gather this information by capturing all ARP broadcast packets on the same subnet that the remote machine sits on.

1. All the IP addresses that the remote machine wants resolved are the IP addresses that the remote machine wants to connect to.
2. All the hosts that want to resolve the IP address of the remote machine are hosts that wish to connect to the remote machine.